# Which scene I need to add firebase code in unity?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I have 3 scene in my game (menu,game,shop). I wrote the code on https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup step 5. Where I need to add this code? All scene or only first scene which is starting.

To which scene or which scenes would you suggest me to add this code to get the most accurate analytics data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code from step 5 is added at the start of the application. It has to fire once on every app launch.

But that is just a general Firebase SDK. Judging from your tags, you're more interested in the analytics side of it. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/unity/start)'s more on the FirebaseAnalytics setup for Unity.